# How to generate a static snapshot of a page in Primefaces?

Tags: ajax, primefaces

I have one website with Primefaces as front-end. So I would like to do static HTML snapshots for all my pages because as I understand Google can't interpret AJAX-based sites. 
Is there any ready-made workflows for that purposes?